# while running rails an error occurs:post_comment_url failed to generate from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error i face during executing is 
post_comment_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>#, :id=>#}, expected: {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}, diff: {:post_id=>#, :id=>#}

Answer (score 0):

In your case `post_comment_url` should receive two parameters: `post id` and `comment id`, like:

```
post_comment_url(@post, @comment)
```